# why always keep display "array"

Tags: php, arrays

I faced problem on fetching data from database. Why the code always keep display "array"?

```
$connection_string = $database.':host='.$host_name.';dbname='.$database_name.';charset='.$charset;
$db = new PDO($connection_string, $database_username, $database_password);

$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$password = $_SESSION['password'];
$query = "SELECT password FROM user ";
$st = $db->prepare($query);
$st->execute();
$result = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo $result;
```

Here, I want to take the data from password column. But when i want to check is it fetch or not but it displaying "array". Anyone can help me? Thank you !

Comment: just use `print_r($result)` instead of `echo $result`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result returned from db are in associative array `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`, `echo` cannot print elements of array, so its prints `array`

Use `print_r($result)` or `var_dump($result)` to print full array

```
printr_r($result);
```

I use a simple function `dd()` in my development to print debug msg

```
//Debug Print Functions
function dd($input, $format = 'var_dump') {
   echo ('<pre style="background-color: #FFFBD5;
        border: 1px solid #F8EBAB; padding: 5px;
        margin:5px 0; box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 #F7FFCD">');
   $format($input);
   echo  ('</pre>');
}
```

Comment: hi Saqueib thanks worked now. Can i ask one more question, is it correct my condition? if($_POST['old_password'] != $result)

Comment: You need `if($_POST['old_password'] != $result[0]['password'])`

Answer (score 0):

You do not refer to each element of the array. You just print the array that will not print the elements of the array. Try this :-

```
foreach( $result as $r){
  echo $r;
}
```

or, use `print_r($result)` (as @Saqueib suggested)

Answer (score 0):

```
$st = $db->prepare($query);
$st->execute();
$result = $st->fetchAll();

print_r($result);
```

See the manual [fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

An also in your case you are getting only password values , so you can try this  way also

```
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
print_r($result);
```

This will print a one dimensional array of passwords